# navbar-fixed-top bootstrap class disables vertical scrolling on page.

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, navbar

I am making my first website using bootstrap (see code below). I have added the navbar-fixed-top class to my page in order to make the navigation bar stick to the top when scrolling down. But instead this class completely disables the possibility to scroll down the page. There simple is no vertical scroll bar on the right side visible anymore. What could the reason behind this be and how can I fix this?

Thanks in advance!

Stijn

```
<nav class="navbar-wrapper navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
<div class="custom-nav">
  <div class="container">
        <div class="col-md-10 col-md-offset-1">

          <div class="navbar-header">
              <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Logo</a>
          </div>
          <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-ex1-collapse">
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                    <li><a href="#">1</a><li>
                    <li><a href="#">2</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">3</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">4</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">5</a></li>
                    <li class="navbarpadding"><form action="#">
                            <button class="btn btn-default btn-primary navbar-btn">Apply</button>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
   </div>
```

Comment: Please let me know if the answer below was the fix or not.

Comment: Yes it fixed the issue. I should start working a bit more structured to avoid these problems in the future I guess. Thanks a lot for helping me out here!

Comment: If you could check the answer correct that would be awesome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easy fix. You did not close your tags appropriately. Be sure that you are closing tags as you open them or else you will run into this problem. This is what your HTML should look like:

HTML:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
    <div class="custom-nav">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="col-md-10 col-md-offset-1">
                <div class="navbar-header"> <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Logo</a>

                </div>
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-ex1-collapse">
                    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
                        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                            <li><a href="#">1</a>

                            </li>
                            <li><a href="#">2</a>

                            </li>
                            <li><a href="#">3</a>

                            </li>
                            <li><a href="#">4</a>

                            </li>
                            <li><a href="#">5</a>

                            </li>
                            <li class="navbarpadding">
                                <form action="#">
                                    <button class="btn btn-default btn-primary navbar-btn">Apply</button>
                                </form>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

**Summary**

You did not close your form tag, an li tag, several div tags, and your nav tag. Whenever you went to put something in the "body" of the document, it would still think that it was part of the navigation bar, which then it would not render it. Just close your tags next time :) I have also left a JSFiddle below of an example to show you that this was the only issue.

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/bC946/4/)**